# Can I re-flash the mainboard on my CR-5 Pro using the USB port instead of the microsd card?

Tags: firmware, creality-ender-5, microsd

I've had a lot of difficulty with my CR-5 Pro not reading the micro SD card. I was up and running but got the "blue screen" yesterday and re-flashed the main board using instructions I found on YouTube. But the software version showing up now is older than what was on the machine as delivered and the printer will not run a gcode file even when I can select it.  Trying to re-flash using the SD card is NOT happening. The SD card that came with the machine is 8Gb "Netoc" and is formatted as FAT32. I have a 32Gb SanDisk which I've formatted also as FAT32 but neither card will re-flash the main board. Can I upload the firmware via USB like I can on an Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .bin files on the SD Card and flashing it that way? If not, you can always use the slicer software that came with it like Creality or I use Cura and through the USB try re-flashing the software that way.